# How to store a cell value in excel and increment it with adjacent changing value?

Tags: excel, vba

Example - I have cell A2 = 10 and B2= 300+A2. The value in B2 will be 310. Now, if I change the value in A2 to 20, I want the value in B2 to automatically change to 330 (and not 300+20). Is there any VBA code or Excel formula which can make this happen?

Comment: You will want to put vba code in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Did you try to change A2 to 20? B2 changes accordingly. That's the idea with Excel.

Comment: @peakpeak but the OP wants to accrue the value not replace.  So each time A2 changes the OP wants B2's current value not a set value, to increas by that amount in A2 and keep that amount then add to it again when A2 changes.  That is why when A2 changes for the second time in the OP's example they want 330 not 320.

Comment: Aishwarya Harne: Nice. You edited the question. Now you tell what you want to accomplish. 
Because what's in your brain and totally evident for you is not in other peoples such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create a macros, and when you do something change, use hotkey (calling this macros).

```
Sub Change()

Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + Range("A2").Value

End sub
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: This don't work at all for me..

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code in a macro :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Dim y As Integer
y = Range("A2").Value 
Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + y
End Sub
```

This sub will detect change value on A2 cell and increment B2 with A2 Cell value.
You can also define a value in B2 Cell, this will increment this value with all A2 Values

Comment: Explain downvote ? this work.. and it's a good solution to answer his problem

Comment: Did not downvote but two things, one your math is wrong.  The OP wants to add the new value each time.  You do not need the x variable and just add A2's value to B2 each time A2 changes. Second item, we should not encourage people who do not show any signs of research or attempts by giving the answer, that is not what this site is for.  So it was one or both those that resulted in the downvote.

Comment: ok, i updated my answer, i did useless step you're right.

Comment: However it's better to downvote the question instead of a correct answer no ?

Comment: Yes I agree, hence why I did not downvote, but it is my policy not to upvote answers to "give me the code" questions either.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the following codes on `Sheet Module` to utilize the `Sheet Change Event`?

`Right click` on `Sheet Tab` -- > `View Code` --> And paste the codes given below into the opened code window --> Close the VB Editor --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

The constant variable `initVal` contains the initial constant value in the formula in `B2` (`=300 + A2`). You may change it as per your requirement.

```
Dim oVal
Const initVal As Long = 300

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A2" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target <> "" Then
        If oVal = "" Then
            Range("B2").Formula = "=A2+" & initVal
        Else
            Range("B2").Formula = "=" & oVal & "+" & Target.Value
        End If
    Else
        Range("B2").Formula = "=A2+" & initVal
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A2" Then
    oVal = Range("B2").Value
End If
End Sub
```